# System keeps booting into windows instead of giving an option to choose

Tags: installation, windows, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my windows with the windows installer. i followed the instructions, and everything was happening as it should have. When it says to reboot, my computer goes for it, but it reboots with my windows 7 instead of giving me the choice as it is supposed to do. What should i do? Thanks.

Comment: 1st you start with a normal title.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the options of the grub menu by pressing one of f-buttons while booting.
I don't know which one as it is not the same for all the computers. (Mine is f8)
For more information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2